# ArgoCD Application Stuck In Syncing/Terminating State

Tags: argocd, argo

We’re facing a weird issue in production where one of the applications is stuck in a terminating and sync state.

**ArgoCD Version: 2.1.7**

**Background**:

We manually terminated the sync of an application and now that the application is stuck in the terminating sync state and the disable auto-sync button also not working.

**Note**:
Creating a new application with similar configs is working but we want to investigate why the current application is stuck.

**Steps performed:**

- We tried disabling the auto-sync from the UI and CLI
- We tried terminating the application
- We tried syncing the app

**Commands tried**

```
argocd app terminate-op APPNAME
argocd app sync APPNAME
argocd app sync APPNAME --force --prune
```

**Some Logs (not sure if these are relevant) :**

```
time="2022-01-07T16:19:36Z" level=debug msg="Failed to apply normalization: error in remove for path: '/spec/preserveUnknownFields': Unable to remove nonexistent key: preserveUnknownFields: missing value"
time="2022-01-07T16:19:36Z" level=debug msg="Failed to apply normalization: error in remove for path: '/status': Unable to remove nonexistent key: status: missing value"
time="2022-01-07T16:19:36Z" level=debug msg="Failed to apply normalization: error in remove for path: '/spec/preserveUnknownFields': Unable to remove nonexistent key: preserveUnknownFields: missing value"
time="2022-01-07T16:19:36Z" level=debug msg="Failed to apply normalization: error in remove for path: '/status': Unable to remove nonexistent key: status: missing value"
time="2022-01-07T16:19:36Z" level=debug msg="Failed to apply normalization: error in remove for path: '/spec/preserveUnknownFields': Unable to remove nonexistent key: preserveUnknownFields: missing value"
time="2022-01-07T16:19:36Z" level=debug msg="Failed to apply normalization: error in remove for path: '/spec/preserveUnknownFields': Unable to remove nonexistent key: preserveUnknownFields: missing value"
time="2022-01-07T16:19:36Z" level=debug msg="Failed to apply normalization: error in remove for path: '/status': Unable to remove nonexistent key: status: missing value"
time="2022-01-07T16:19:36Z" level=debug msg="Failed to apply normalization: error in remove for path: '/spec/preserveUnknownFields': Unable to remove nonexistent key: preserveUnknownFields: missing value"
time="2022-01-07T16:19:36Z" level=debug msg="patch: {\"status\":{\"reconciledAt\":\"2022-01-07T16:19:36Z\"}}" application=argocd
time="2022-01-07T16:19:36Z" level=info msg="Failed to Update application operation state: etcdserver: request is too large, retrying in 1s"time="2022-01-07T16:19:36Z" level=info msg="Update successful" application=argocd
time="2022-01-07T16:19:36Z" level=info msg="Reconciliation completed" application=argocd dedup_ms=0 dest-name= dest-namespace=argocd dest-server="https://417901E660A9365B4057207C70C682EE.gr7.ap-south-1.eks.amazonaws.com" diff_ms=174 fields.level=2 git_ms=13 health_ms=3 live_ms=1 settings_ms=0 sync_ms=0 time_ms=249
time="2022-01-07T16:19:36Z" level=info msg="Refreshing app status (controller refresh requested), level (1)" application=argocd
```

When trying to run the sync again or terminating the sync

```
time="2022-01-07T18:08:00Z" level=warning msg="finished unary call with code FailedPrecondition" error="rpc error: code = FailedPrecondition desc = another operation is already in progress" grpc.code=FailedPrecondition grpc.method=Sync grpc.service=application.ApplicationService grpc.start_time="2022-01-07T18:08:00Z" grpc.time_ms=484.012 span.kind=server system=grpc
```

[image: argo cd sync issue]

[image: argocd sync]

[image: argocd sync issues]

Comment: Any solution found for the `'/spec/preserveUnknownFields': Unable to remove nonexistent key: preserveUnknownFields: missing value` error?

Comment: AFAK argocd uses finalizers. So a common advice when kubernetes gets stuck is to remove finalizer. That's what I would try, not sure if it helps.